# (Friedberg) Eigenvalue of a linear operator T iff eigenvalue of [T]

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I ask a question since I can't read one sentence of "Linear algebra(by Friedberg)" organically.

In the preceding paragraph of Example 5 of the chapter 5.1, this book says that since similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial, the definition of characteristic polynomial f(t) of a linear operator T doesn't depend of the choice of basis and I followed so far.

The sentence in question is next one.
"Thus if T is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space V and β is an ordered basis for V, then λ is an eigenvalue of T if and only if λ is an eigenvalue of [T]_β."

Here is my question. In my thought the preceding sentences are just saying that characteristic polynomial is independent of the choice of basis. So I think that sentence right after should be justified. Am I right? Does this book omit justification?

[image]

Comment: This question lacks context. How does Friedberg define eigenvalue of a linear endomorphism (my guess is that if $V$ is a vector space and $T\colon V\longrightarrow V$ is a linear map, then he says that an eigenvalues of $T$ is a scalar $\lambda$ such that, for some $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$, $T(v)=\lambda v$). How does Friedberg define eigenvalue of a square matrix? Does he prove show the relationship between eigenvalues and characteristic polynomials?

Comment: I agree in part, but I couldn't move the whole book context. The definition of the eigenvalues of a linear operator is as good as you write them down, and the definition of the eigenvalues of a matrix is Av=λv for some nonzero v in F^n. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @MSLee I agree that the statement that $T$ and $[T]_\beta$ have the same eigenvalues doesn't (at least not obviously) follow from the statements proceeding it. If the characteristic polynomial is independent of one's choice of basis, then it follows that the eigenvalues are independent of one's choice of basis since the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, but I don't see how that gets us any closer to the conclusion in question.

Answer (score 1):

As I state in my comment, I'm not sure how exactly the authors meant to reach the conclusion that $T$ and $[T]_\beta$ have the same eigenvalues from the fact that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is basis invariant. However, based on the definition of an eigenvector discussed in the comments, it's not too difficult to show this directly. It suffices to note that the following statements are equivalent

- $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T:V \to V$
- There exists a non-zero vector $v \in V$ for which $Tv = \lambda v$
- There exists a non-zero vector $v \in V$ for which $[T]_\beta[v]_\beta = \lambda [v]_\beta$
- There exists a non-zero vector $x \in \Bbb F^n$ for which $[T]_\beta x = \lambda x$
- $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $[T]_\beta$

Comment: Thanks very much!